# Wrap content of items individually in a Recycler View?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to figure out how to do this in the most simple way possible. Setting the recycler view to wrap the content of course, adjusts the recycler to the biggest item. Setting it to match_parent adjusts all the items to be the maximum at all times.

Setting the maximum width in the Adapter makes all the items be that size no matter what. Dumbfounded at the moment.

My Adapter class

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Message> messageList;
    private Context context;
    private MessageSelectListener messageSelectListener;

    public MessageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Message> messageList){
        this.messageList = messageList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    //Create an interface
    public interface MessageSelectListener{
        void onMessageClick(Message message, int position);
    }

    public void setMessageClickListener(MessageSelectListener messageSelectListener){
        this.messageSelectListener = messageSelectListener;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_list, parent, false);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        view.setLayoutParams(lp);
        //View view = new TextView(context);
        //View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.order_list, parent, false);


        return new MessageViewHolder(view);




    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        final Message message = messageList.get(position);
        holder.text.setText(message.getMessageText());

        holder.text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner_white_noborder);

        // passing Order and Position as parameter to interface method,
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                messageSelectListener.onMessageClick(message, position);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messageList == null ? 0 : messageList.size();
    }


    public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView text;
        public Message message;

        public MessageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text = (TextView) itemView;
        }




    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what's happening now vs. what you want to happen?

Comment: So right now, I have a recycler view for a chat room. The text inside the chat bubbles variates and I'd like the width of the Recycler Items to expand according to the amount of text inside of them. Right now I have the recycler view to "match_parent", this makes the width of the chat bubbles take the whole width of the screen. If I set it to "wrap_content", the chat bubbles will expand as text is added but all the chat bubbles will be the same size until eventually they match the screen's width. I'd like for each chat bubble to have its own width according to the text inside it.

Comment: You want to make the RecyclerView ``match_parent`` (so it has a fixed size) but have the ViewHolder layout (which each item uses) set to ``wrap content``, so each item in the list is just sized to its content

Comment: Oh wait you're doing that in code huh - it could be that when the ViewHolder is reused it's not actually remeasuring itself, like it's calculated in ``onCreateViewHolder`` and never changes unless it needs to expand? You could try ``holder.itemView.requestLayout()`` in ``onBindViewHolder`` to force a recalculation when an item is reused (after you've set the content)

Comment: I figured it out posting the answer. Also thank you for the help, I believe this tied it together.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution was to change the layout parameters in the onCreateViewHolder() method to **WRAP_CONTENT**

```
 @NonNull
    @Override
    public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_list, parent, false);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.**WRAP_CONTENT**, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        view.setLayoutParams(lp);
        //View view = new TextView(context);
        //View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.order_list, parent, false);


        return new MessageViewHolder(view);




    }
```